# Чекбоксы без кнопки submit в моем коде

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Как реализовать чекбоксы с моментальной отправкой формы без кнопки "submit"? 
Мой код:

```
<form method="post" style="width: 1000px;text-align: center;margin: auto;">

    <label><input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Gang zones"> <span class="checkbox-custom"></span> <span class="label">Территории</span></label> 

    <label><input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Bases"> <span class="checkbox-custom"></span> <span class="label">Базы</span></label> 

    <label><input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Houses"> <span class="checkbox-custom"></span> <span class="label">Дома</span></label> 

    <label><input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Bunkers"> <span class="checkbox-custom"></span> <span class="label">Бункеры</span></label> 

    <label><input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Businesses"> <span class="checkbox-custom"></span> <span class="label">Бизнессы</span></label> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        var data = $($(this).parents('form:first')).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: '/',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: а если форм на странице несколько? А если в других формах есть чекбоксы? Сомнительное решение

Comment: можно предположить очень много "если". а если javascript отключен?) вполне норм. будет несколько форм - значит нужной форме поставят какой-нибудь идентификатор/класс/что-нибудь еще и изменят селектор в этом скрипте.

Comment: Вставил этот скрипт, почему-то не работает. Или нужно еще что-то кроме скрипта?

Comment: Может не работать по многим причинам:
не подключен jquery:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`
или ф-я вызывается раньше подключения скрипта. а вообще проще открыть консоль браузера и посмотреть

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: Я в таких случаях первым делом иду в гугл и смотрю, что значит данное сообщение об ошибке.

99%, что код был криво скопирован - может получилось нечётное кол-во скобок :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Gang zones"
  onclick="this.closest('form').submit()">
```

> А можно без обновления страницы?

```
<iframe name="frameforform" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form method="post" style="width: 1000px;text-align: center;margin: auto;"
  target="frameforform">
  ...
```

```html
<form method="post" style="text-align: center;margin: auto;"
  target="frameforform">
<label><input class="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" type="checkbox" value="Gang zones"
  onclick="this.closest('form').submit();console.log('submitted - ',this.checked);" />Click</label>
</form>
<iframe name="frameforform" style="display1:none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: А можно без обновления страницы?

Comment: Страница все равно обновляется, onclick="this.closest('form').submit() нужно убрать?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код :). Смотрите пример в ответе.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Появляется какая-то квадрат если вставляю этот код. И страница все равно обновляется

Comment: @CoffeeinTime https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Comment: Можете просто вставить то что нужно в мой код? Я запутался окончательно. https://pastebin.com/ASrWAGLe